# What is a good German idiom for "straight and narrow?"

Tags: english-to-german, idiom, phrase-request

I’m referring to the tendency of some people to follow a straight, unbranched path, with no deviations. For instance, waiting for a stoplight to change to green even at midnight even though there are no cars coming from a perpendicular direction.

The expression that I use is *streng and eng.* It is direct and straightforward, and even rhymes, so IMHO, it does the job. Is this, however, “standard” German, or is there a more idiomatic way to express this idea?

Comment: linguee says "sittenstreng" ( [look here](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?query=straight+and+narrow) ). You can also see there that there are a lot of ways to translate it. In your case, I would maybe use "prinzipientreu".

Comment: *sittenstreng* is way off. That's more like "prude". *prinzipientreu* is better, but has a notion of merely following *your own rules* instead of those of others.

Comment: @tofro: "Sittenstreng" is "not bad" IMHO. Yes, it does have the connotations of "prude" but I consider that a virtue. Maybe there is "no better." So "streng" was in the right direction, but "eng" moved it too far toward "engstirnig."

Comment: well, *prude* is, at least nowadays, something most Germans would not exactly consider a virtue. Your call, however.

Comment: Please don't abuse comments to answer the question. Use answers instead, please.

Comment: @tofro I assume that Tom means that the connotations of "prude" are a virtue of the translation "sittenstreng", since "straight and narrow" also has slightly negative connotations.

Comment: Since when is answering the question in comments "abuse"?

Comment: @Pekka웃: Normally it's better to post an answer than a comment. But tofro can be excused since he already posted an answer, and wanted to keep it separate from his comment on ixolius' comment.

Comment: What you're describing isn't quite what the English idiom "straight and narrow" (correctly "strait and narrow") means. “Strait is the gate and narrow is the way which leadeth unto life,” i.e. it's difficult to attain Heaven and relatively few people do it.

Comment: @sgf does it? Not as far as I understand it.

Comment: @tofro _I’m referring to the tendency of some people to follow a straight, unbranched path, with no deviations. For instance, waiting for a stoplight to change to green even at midnight even though there are no cars coming from a perpendicular direction._ That's a positive trait in your eyes?

Comment: @sgf I was only referring to what "straight and narrow" actually means - Nothing else.

Comment: @tofro Ah, I see. You're right, it doesn't seem to have negative connotations, but it does seem to have them in the eyes of the OP, and that's what I was referring to.

Comment: @sgf Hmm. Where does he say that?

Comment: @tofro I thought it evident from the example that he gave for a use of the expression. (The one I quoted 4 comments up from this), and I thought it was the most natural way to understand _Yes, it does have the connotations of "prude" but I consider that a virtue._ since prude is (by definition?) not a virtue. (That is, I thought _that_ referred to it having the connotations, not to the word "prude", and a virtue of the translation rather than a virtue in general.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The word you are looking for is **geradlinig**.

> Walter ist sehr geradlinig. Wenn er eine Sache anfängt, zieht er sie auch durch.

Comment: The best fit by far. It almost exactly matches the image of "following a straight path" (path ~> line - even more straightness!) and it is connotated positively.

Comment: @Annatar Not sure - Misses the aspect of "following common rules".  If a person who is "geradlinig" decides it would be a good idea to cross the street at a *red* traffic light, he will do so. Close to *prinzipientreu* in a comment above.

Comment: In the English idiom "straight and narrow" as I know it, a person who is described so would never cross the street at a red traffic light unless it was to perform some morally superior act in a rare emergency.  "Straight and narrow" does not mean simply "straight and direct" as geradlinig appears to mean, but has a strong connotation of always following the rules and deepest-held traditions... at least, as I understand it.

Comment: *Geradlinig* also means following the rules, once set. You may set your own rules but follow them afterwards. *Straight and direct* has to be translated *geradeheraus*.

Answer (score 10):

It depends a bit whether you want to express this trait as positive or rather as (partially) negative. I'm assuming a positive notion from your question. Then you might want to look along the lines of

- *tugendhaft* and
- *immer auf dem rechten Pfad der Tugend gehend*.
- *tadellos* und
- *frei von jedem Tadel* might fit as well.
- *gesetzestreu* and
- *hochanständig* could also be used.

*streng und eng*  would probably not be understood or understood wrongly. That is not idiomatic in German and too close to *engstirnig*, which is "bigoted" and "narrow-minded". *engstirnig* and *pedantisch* could, however, be used for the more negative notions of this attribute.

Comment: I consider this trait positive. So the closeness of my expression to "engstirnig" was a pitfall I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

What about

> - [anständig](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anstaendig)
> - [gewissenhaft](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gewissenhaft)
> - [solid[e]](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/solid)
> - [konform](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/konform)

?

Comment: Not a bad answer.

Answer (score 3):

I want to explain some idioms from the question and from other answers, to give you a chance to understand and compare them:

- **streng and eng**
  *»and«* is not a German word, but even *»streng und eng«* will not work in German. Nobody will understand what you mean. Maybe some English native speakers might understand it because they might translate it back into english, and then understand the English idiom.

  *»streng and/und eng«* is like translating German idioms word by word into English, like in this example:
  *»My English is not the yellow from the egg, but it goes«.* (The German idiom is: *»Mein Englisch ist nicht das Gelbe vom Ei, aber es geht«*, and a correct translation would be: *»My English is not exactly brilliant, but it's ok.«*)
- **streng**
  This word can mean: *severe, strict, stiff, stringent, draconic, grim, austere*
  None of this meanings has a really positive connotation. *»Streng«* is a property, that police officers, judges, teachers, parents and directors can have.
- **eng**
  This word has a very different meaning. It can mean: *tight, narrow, close*
  If an alley is so narrow, that hardly one car can pass through, then it is *»eng«*. Trousers, that are so tight, that you hardly can close the zip, are *»eng«*. In German there is absolutely no idiomatic connection between *»eng«* and *»straight and narrow«*. (See also *»engstirnig«*)
- **engstirnig**
  When I did read *»streng und eng«*, then my first association was *»engstirnig«*, because *»eng«* doesn't make any sense in combination with *»streng«* (as described above). But *»engstirng«* is: *narrow-minded, small-minded, parochial, blinkered, hidebound, close-minded*
- **sittenstreng**
  This word carries all connotations that are in *»streng«* (see above), plus all connotations of *»Sitte«* or *»sittlich«.* The noun *»Sitte«* can mean *morals, convention, customs, manners*
  The adjective *»sittlich«* is: *ethical, moral*
  So, *»sittenstreng«* is *puritanical, strait-laced, strict and grim with morals.*
- **prinzipientreu**
  The noun *»Prinzip«* means *»principle, set of believes«* and the adjective *treu* is *faithful, allegiant, loyal, constant*. So the compound adjective *prinzipientreu* is *principled, faithful to the own convictions*, but it also has a connotation of *»... without thinking about wether this convictions are right or wrong«*
- **tugendhaft**
  There is not really a good englisch translation for the German noun *Tugend*. I just find *virtue* and *goodness*, but both have much a much wider field of meaning than the German word. A »Tugend« is a morally high-quality property, that a person can have. And the adjective *»tugendhaft«* is used to describe the morally flawless behavior of such a person. It has a strong connotation with ethics and moral. I think *morally* is a good translation for *tugendhaft*.
- **auf dem (rechten) Pfad der Tugend gehen**
  This is a idiom that just is a longer way to say *»tugendhaft«* or *»sehr tugendhaft«* (*very morally*)
- **tadellos**
  The noun *»Tadel«* means *blame, flaw* and the suffix *-los* is *-less*. So this adjective means *blameless, flawless, immaculate* and has a respectful positive (even a little bit admiring) connotation.
- **frei von jedem Tadel**
  Just a longer way to say *tadellos*
- **gesetzestreu**
  I explained *treu* already (look at *prinzipientreu*). The noun »Gesetz« is »the law, the laws. So *gesetzestreu* is *law-abiding*.
- **anständig**
  The adjective *anständig* is derived from the noun *»der Anstand«*  which means *decency, decorum, integrity*. So *anständig* is *fair, decent, modest*.
- **hochanständig**
  The adjective *hochanständig* ist just an enhancement of *anständig*.
- **pedantisch**
  This is *pettifogging, finical, micrological, niggling*
- **geradlinig**
  Literally this means *along a straight line* (*gerade* is *straight, direct*; *Linie* is *line, route*) and can be translated as *upright, straightforward, no-nonsense, straight*
- **gewissenhaft**
  This is *conscientious, scrupulous, assiduously, painstaking*
- **solide**
  *firm, respectable, strong*

Comment: What, in your opinion, is the difference between "Tugend" and "virtue" (and thus, "tugendhaft" and "virtuous")? I have always treated those as exact translations of each other.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: I am not so good in English, maybe I am wrong. But I think that *virtue* also has a connotation of *benefit* (Vorteil, Wert, Vorzug) that is not in the German word *»Tugend«*. Plus: *virtue* can also be translated as *»Heilkraft«* (*healing power*) (of herbs for example), and this meaning is definitely not a meaning of *»Tugend«*. Another meaning of *virtue* seems to be *chastity* (*Keuschheit*). Some people might say, that *Keuschheit* is a *Tugend* (like »a *house* is a *building*«) but *Keuschheit* and *Tugend* (as well as *house* and *building*) do not mean the same.

Comment: Note that even a serial killer could easily qualify as *geradlinig* and *prinzipientreu* as long as he goes straight for his targets and applies the same principles  - Both entirely miss the ethical notion.

Answer (score 2):

The straight and narrow is "**der Pfad der Tugend**" in German, but this is kind of an archaic expression (as are many suggestions that have been made already). Think Shakespeare. It can also be translated as "**die rechte Bahn**", but this has more of a connotation of being normal and slipping into crime would be to deviate from the "rechte Bahn" (right road). Which is also an old fashioned expression not in common use anymore. (Since about a decade or two, I'd say.)

The straight and narrow, I think, expresses more of an inherent incapability to judge situations for what they are and instead follow rules blindly, like the traffic light example. It's a subtle way to mock someone for doing the right thing.

As such, I would suggest "**Gutmensch**". It describes someone that always does the right thing, even if it is to his own detriment and it is also not meant as praise, but to mock such a person.

Comment: Agree with your first two proposals, but don't agree with "Gutmensch" -  this is not used to describe any positive notion at all. *Straight and narrow* is, however.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one choice not yet mentiond

> zielstrebig

is in my opinion quite close to the favourite *geradlinig* and would still fit when the person follows a moderately meandering path, but with the strong intention to follow it up to the end.

Comment: Doesn't fit in my opinion - Does not cover the ethical aspect and does not cover the "path of virtue" the English expression has. Could maybe fit together with another adjective.

Answer (score 1):

> strikt (Adj.)

http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/strikt
http://dict.leo.org/german-english/strikt

.. someone who does not allow much space for interpretation of things and follows the rules.

Comment: that is true for "strikt", but does not fit "straight and narrow" well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best fit is

**aufrichtig**

It describes the positive quality of being honest and
good and also indicates that the person will not deviate
from this path even if it would have advantages.

Another word which describes more the being strict
to themselves part:

**unbeugsam**

describing a person which will not yield or change
its behavior whatever comes. It could be described
as negative trait for having rigid behavior, but
mostly it has the positive connection that the person
will not be dominated by anyone.